# Why are some packages missing in Debian Testing that are available in Stable and Unstable? How do you install those packages?

Tags: debian, package-management

I am setting up a machine with Debian Testing (Bullseye). I found that some packages are not available in Testing, but they are in Stable (Buster) and in Unstable (Sid).

For example:

LibreCAD: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=librecad

Owncloud Client: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=owncloud-client

Why are some packages in Stable and Unstable, but not in Testing?

What is the recommended way to install such packages on Testing?
(I simply added the "Stable" branch to my sources.list, but I believe this smells like FrankenDebian.)

Comment: See 3.1.5 to 3.1.7 on this [Debian FAQ](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-choosing.en.html)

Comment: and to know the reason for a specific package, look at the debian package tracker. eg: https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/owncloud-client

Comment: The points 3.1.5 to 3.1.7 in the Debian FAQ make sense to me if the package in Unstable is a newer version than the one in Stable. However, this is not the case in my two examples (LibreCAD and Owncloud Client). They are the SAME version on Stable and Unstable, so I don't understand why they are missing in Testing.